# Default initialization of unused constant variable template

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, uninitialized-constant

The following [program](https://godbolt.org/z/s6KWMK):

```
template<typename = void> 
const int n;
```

is compiled successfully by gcc, but clang gives an error:

```
# error: default initialization of an object of const type 'const int'
const int n;
          ^
            = 0
```

which makes sense.

gcc does give an error if `n` is used, but is a diagnostic required even if `n` is unused?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is a diagnostic required even if `n` is unused?

No. The applicable rule is [[temp.res.general]/8](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/temp.res.general#8):

> The validity of a template may be checked prior to any instantiation.
>
> The program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required, if:
>
> - no valid specialization can be generated for a template or a substatement of a constexpr if statement within a template and the template is not instantiated, or
> - ...
> - a hypothetical instantiation of a template immediately following its definition would be ill-formed due to a construct that does not depend on a template parameter, or
> - ...

So both compilers are complying with the Standard.